# undefined method permit for update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

***my code like  this. i am using rails guide tutorial***

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
```

***error is here***

```
    def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

**in controller distroy method like this**

```
    def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

        redirect_to display_posts_path
    end

    private

    def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_attributes` for updating the values of that variable.

change:

```
@post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
```

To:

```
@post.update_attributes(:title => params[:post][:title], :text => params[:post][:text])
```

hope it helps !!

Comment: i tried but how to accepted the answer i select the vote also but nthing done

Comment: Just click the up arrow along with my answer. You can also see a correct sign under the arrow. You can also select for accepting the answer.